# Text Recognition API

Tags: gratis, android, ios, api, ocr

I am working on a dictionary App for Android and iOS. Where I want to have feature like place the camera on a word and the app will recognize the word and will show the meaning of that word.

For example, the "U Dictionary" app is a full fledged working app with such functionality. Can someone please let me know which API needs to be used? Is it available FREE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was an attempt at a [free Android OCR library using the Tesseract OCR engine here](https://github.com/rebbix/tesseract-android-tools/tree/master/tesseract-android-tools). However, the code there seems to be rather old (6 to 7 years), and I’m not sure if anyone tried to update it or build a newer free library. I also don’t know if there’s any documentation for that library.

As for iOS, it appears someone created a wrapper for Tesseract OCR to work on iOS, [as explained by this article.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/306-tesseract-ocr-tutorial-for-ios).

Comment: Thanks Amin for your reply and answer. That answers my query. 

Cheers, 

Tanuj K.